# I can't open my tablet (even after long press) when someone manually shuts it down

Tags: tablet

If someone clicks the "Shut down" button (not power button) on Asus Tablet, it will stay shut down and it won't open even after I long press the power button. It only opens after I connect it to a charger, and then long press the power button. But I don't have the charger with me all the time, what can I do? Is there any software or something to download? I forgot the exact name of the tablet but it's made by Asus and I got it in 2016

Comment: What long is a "long press"? Have you tried to enable a force reboot by holding the power button for more than 10 or 30 seconds?

Comment: One or two times it was very long, maybe like 3 or 4 minutes

Comment: Is there any application or something I need to do?